# Face error in use entity-and and entity-one

Tags: xml, ofbiz

I am new to **ofbiz**, I am using  in form.xml but when I use  with same  it is giving errors.

my code is:

```
 <entity-and entity-name="AssetAuthor" list="allAuthors">
   <field-map field-name="assetRefId" from-field="assetRefId" />        
 </entity-and>
```

when I do same with  doesn't works. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using

```
<entity-one></entity-one>
```

you need to pass primary-key of the table.In your case there would be a composite primary key,so you have to pass all keys in field-map tag.